# Usage of the word "truancy" in a workplace context

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, word-usage, analogy

I recently made this personal discovery of the word *truancy*. It means:

> the action of staying away from school without good reason

I am wondering if there's a parallel to this word for workplace or professional settings.

All I can think of is *absenteeism*, but it doesn't capture the essence of *truancy*.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/truancy

Comment: You can just use truancy. It means being absent without permission, nothing to do with school. School is just the most common setting for the word.

Comment: 'Skiving' would be the word I use. Although my understanding is that it is almost exclusively a British term. e.g. 'He's skiving off work today.' 'He's such a skiver.'

Answer (score 4):

***absenteeism*** actually is the word you're looking for.

> absenteeism
>
> : the act of staying away from work without a good reason.
>
> [Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/107981552/bua-330-exam-3-flash-cards/)
>
> : the act of staying away from work without permission or prior notice.
>
> [Sweetwater Reporter](http://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth282523/m1/4/)

Alternately, you might consider

***cutting work***

> cut
>
> : to fail to attend purposely: *cut a class*.
>
> [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cut)
>
> cut class *and* cut school
>
> : to skip a school class or a day of school without an excuse. *As a joke, one day all the students cut their math class and went to lunch.* *Jane was grounded after she cut school last Friday.*
>
> (McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

***skipping work***

> skip
>
> : to fail to attend or participate in *skip the tournament*
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skip)
>
> *Half of MPS students regularly skip school, report shows*
>
> [Journal Sentinel](http://www.jsonline.com/news/education/32540454.html?ipad=y)

***ditching work***

> ditch
>
> : *Slang* to skip (class or school)
>
> [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ditch)
>
> *tv. & in.* to skip or evade someone or something. *Pete ditched class today.*
>
> (McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions)
>
> *Truancy can be described as any unauthorized absence from school, cutting school, skipping school, ditching school, etc.*
>
> [Red Bluff Police Department](http://www.rbpd.org/copscorner_truancy.php)
>
> *Even the President is ditching work to see Star Wars*

Answer (score 2):

The military term AWOL (Absent without leave) is recognized in non-military context.

Answer (score 1):

**[Playing hooky](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hooky)** is a common phrase used in the US, primarily, but not exclusively, relating to school

> (informal (mainly US & Canadian & New Zealand) truancy, usually from school (esp in the phrase *play hooky*)

This is frequently used to describe absence in the workplace, and it has a naughty, childish connotation.

When the unauthorized absence is organized among several workers, it may be called a **[sick-out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sick%20out)**. Among uniformed services, such as police or firefighters, it is sometimes called the **[blue flu](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blue+flu)**.